# I create a file that is time stamped and for some reason I cant get newlines into the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, echo

A few commands I tried are

```
printf "%s\n" >> file$DATE.txt
echo -e "\n" >> file$DATE.txt
```

What can be going on? Is it because I use Notepad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes.

Notepad only understands DOS line-endings and not Unix line-endings. Use Wordpad or any other more capable editor to see the newlines correctly.

Alternatively, if you do want to create DOS/Windows line-ending files then use `\r\n` in the `printf` call as Barmar indicates in his comment.

Comment: Or use `\r\n` in the `printf` to create DOS line endings.

Comment: @Alan The extension doesn't matter. That's a Windows-ism. The contents are all that matters.